# Unable to break out of "while" loop - C

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to implement a simple while loop to let the user enter multiple marks without having to reload the application, for some reason no matter what i seem to enter it always loops.

I've looked using the debugger and it doesn't seem to accept the final scanf() asking whether to repeat itself or not.

```
int mark = 0;
    char grade;
    char choice = 'y';

    while(choice == 'y')
    {
        //Request input
        printf("enter a mark: ");
        scanf("%d", &mark);

        //Assess mark
        grade = assess(mark);

        //Output result
        printf("That equals ");
        printf("%c", grade);
        printf(" when graded\n");

        //Repeat?
        printf("Again?...\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("&c", &choice);
    }
```

I've also tried it with a do - while loop and still no joy, any idea where the problem may lie?

Comment: The scanf() isn't doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Last scanf should be scanf("%c",&choice) surely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least two problems:

```
  fflush(stdin);
```

is undefined - you can only flush output streams. And:

```
    scanf("&c", &choice);
```

should be:

```
    scanf("%c", &choice);
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is also bad in situations where the operation *is* defined, since it will break batch processing, e.g. `grader < listofgrades.txt > results.txt`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the answer. I keep getting "&" and "%" mixed up for some reason. I never normally use fflush but found it mentioned in a few forum posts whilst searching the internet.

Comment: fflush(stdout), yes, it's very frequently used.
If you want to print out anything without putting a newline at the end (say, updating a progress meter), you need to fflush(stdout) to have the new data to appear.
fflush(stdin) - nope, no real sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think last line should be

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
```

instead of

```
scanf("&c", &choice);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fflush()` is only defined for output streams.  The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html) does not recommend using it for `stdin`.

Also, as others have noted, use `scanf("%c", &choice);` to read the choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try `scanf("%c", &choice);`.

Note that scanf returns the number of inputs matched, so you should really check the return value. If the input does not, for som reason, map to a character, your variable might be unchanged. Before the call to scanf, set `choice` to something `!= 'y'`, so that you only continue if a `y` is input.